# Matlab cannot read "numeric" field from csv

Tags: matlab, csv

I am trying to read a csv file into Matlab using the following command

> data=csvread('/econ/research/rd123/RAIS/Chuhang/data/final_samples/growth_regs_RandI_ALL.csv',1,0);

But matlab produced the following message:

> {Error using dlmread (line 138) Mismatch between file and format
>   string. Trouble reading 'Numeric' field from file (row number 1, field
>   number 1) ==>
>   "00000000000272",440,"65","13007",1995,6586,.1776316,-.1045213,.2821529,.0000105,.0002363,.0378644,.0078976\n
>
> Error in csvread (line 47)
>       m=dlmread(filename, ',', r, c);
>
> Error in import_all_mfn (line 13)
>   data=csvread('/econ/research/rd123/RAIS/Chuhang/data/final_samples/growth_regs_RandI_ALL.csv',1,0);

Does anyone know what the problem might be? Thanks in advance!

-Chuhang

Comment: It looks like your data contains a quoted character string in row 1 field 1, not a number.

Comment: Yes that is exactly the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 T = readtable(filename);
 firstcolumn = T{:,1};
```

This function reads all table but you must use indices as cells.

Also there is an explanation here.
https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html

Answer (score 0):

`dlmread` and `csvread` only work for numeric values. try using `textread` instead: http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textread.html

here you can define your custom format and cast (i.e. `str2double`) the numeric values, which are in your file as a quoted character string.